# How to run ETL pipeline on Databricks (Python)

Tags: python, apache-spark, spark-streaming, databricks, amazon-kinesis

I am trying to create a live sentiment analysis model using kinesis datastreams and a databricks notebook using spark. I noticed that my code blocks that do the data transformation, building the model, analyzing sentiment, and sending data to a database only runs once when, but I want those code blocks to run continuously until I decide to stop their execution. Is there a way in databricks to have code blocks run continuously until the user decides to kill their execution?

I tried running my notebook as a job, but the code block that handles the spark streaming just runs forever and never allows the other codeblocks complete the ETL process.

Is this a problem with how I set up my spark stream? Here is the code on how I set it up:

```
kinesisDF = spark \
  .readStream \
  .format("kinesis") \
  .option("streamName", kinesisStreamName)\
  .option("region", kinesisRegion) \
  .option("initialPosition", "latest") \
  .option("format", "json") \
  .option("awsAccessKey", awsAccessKeyId)\
  .option("awsSecretKey", awsSecretKey) \
  .option("inferSchema", "true") \
  .load()
```

```
df = kinesisDF \
  .writeStream \
  .format("memory") \
  .outputMode("append") \
  .queryName("tweets")  \
  .start()
```

the codeblock above (.start) is the codeblock that runs continuously when I try and run the notebook as a job and does not allow the other codeblocks to execute. P.S. I am pretty new to databricks and spark

Comment: i did the DB course recently and even on CE not an issue. Use another cell or open a new tab. I find the question not easy to follow.

Comment: @thebluephantom sorry for the question structure. the other code that handles the ETL process are in other code blocks in the same notebook. The problem is that they won't  continuously run while the spark stream is grabbing more data from the kinesis data stream. They will run once and use that snapshot of data that is currently in that df that contains the spark stream to run the process and send to dynamodb. Is this just a problem on how I am running my notebook?

Comment: that souds reasonable, that those others run once

Comment: pls show that code

Answer (score 2):

I think you need to follow the approach for Dynamo DB as Sink as per https://docs.databricks.com/spark/latest/structured-streaming/examples.html#write-to-amazon-dynamodb-using-foreach-in-scala-and-python using a `foreach`.

From the DB manuals to get you going - focus on `foreach`:

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import *

spark.conf.set("spark.sql.shuffle.partitions", "1")

query = (
  spark.readStream.format("rate").load()
       .selectExpr("value % 10 as key")
       .groupBy("key")
       .count()
       .toDF("key", "count")
       .writeStream
       .foreach(SendToDynamoDB_ForeachWriter())
      #.foreach(sendToDynamoDB_simple)  // alternative, use one or the other
       .outputMode("update")
       .start()'
)
```

streamingDF.writeStream.foreach() allows you to write the output of a streaming query to arbitrary locations. That's the clue here.

Comment: Okay thanks, I will try it out. What I am streaming to the Database is JSON objects. These JSON objects are stored in a list which is then iterated over to send to the database.

Comment: That's fine, but you need to have the continuity for a "foreign" sink as it were.

Comment: Okay, I get the streaming for the database, but how do I have my sentiment analysis model in my notebook run continuously as well since I need to analyze the new streaming data from my spark stream and then send the results to the database?

Comment: to learn incrementally or run against a trained model?

Comment: I am using the textblob library so it just analyzes the sentiment right there and assigns the tweet a sentiment value

Comment: No experience with that

Answer (score 0):

Coding ETL forms in Python can take numerous structures, contingent upon specialized prerequisites, business goals, which libraries existing tools are good with, and how much designers feel they have to work without any preparation. Python's qualities lie in working with recorded information structures and word references, which are significant in ETL tasks.

Python is adaptable enough that clients can code practically any ETL procedure with local information structures. For instance, sifting invalid qualities through of a rundown is simple with some assistance from the inherent Python math module:

import math data = [1.0, 3.0, 6.5, float('NaN'), 40.0, float('NaN')] filtered = [] for value in data: if not math.isnan(value): filtered.append(value)

Coding the whole ETL process without any preparation isn't especially proficient, so most ETL code winds up being a blend of unadulterated Python code and remotely characterized capacities or articles, for example, those from libraries referenced previously. For example, clients can utilize pandas to channel a whole DataFrame of lines containing nulls:

sifted = data.dropna()

Python programming improvement packs (SDK), application programming interfaces (API), and different utilities are accessible for some stages, some of which might be helpful in coding for ETL. For instance, the Anaconda stage is a Python appropriation of modules and libraries important for working with information. It incorporates its own bundle chief and cloud facilitating for sharing code scratch pad and Python conditions.

A great part of the counsel significant for the most part coding in Python additionally applies to programming for ETL. For instance, the code ought to be "Pythonic" — which implies developers ought to follow some language-explicit rules that make contents compact and clear and speak to the software engineer's goals. Documentation is additionally significant, just as great bundle the board and keeping an eye out for conditions.